# Cannot Cast png to bitmap

Tags: c#, windows, bitmap, png, aforge

I'm attempting to convert a image to bitmap so that i can make it rotate based on angles received through the serial port, and then output the resultant image to a pictureBox. however this results in either a build failure or the image wont show on the screen. i am using the AForge Imaging.Filters framework to achieve this. current code:

```
private void imageRotate(int angle)
    {
        int angleToMove = angle; //- lastAngle;
        Bitmap image = Properties.Resources.Compass_Transparent;
        pictureBox1.Image = null;

        RotateBilinear ro = new RotateBilinear(angleToMove, true);


        ro.FillColor = Color.White;

        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;

        Bitmap image2 = ro.Apply(image);
        pictureBox1.Image = image2;
        lastAngle = angle;
    }
```

i am able to achieve the desired effect by using

```
Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"path");
```

and i can currently set the pictureBox to the image initially by using

```
img = TableTurner.Properties.Resources.Compass_Transparent;
pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

however this does not work when trying to reference the resources file.

Comment: Can you apply the rotation on a Clone of the Bitmap?

Comment: "this does not work" - what exactly does not work? What does it do? If the build fails. what is your error?